# Get or Create a Context From Within an Android Java Process

Tags: java, android, dex, termux

Is it possible to start a .dex file using `dalvikvm` from inside of an app or ADB shell, and then get the caller app context or create a new context to use in API calls?

For example, could I run `dalvikvm -cp [class].dex [class]` and show a toast message using `Toast.makeText()`?

For reference, I'm running Android Nougat 7.1 (API level 25).

Answer (score 0):

No. A dex file running with dalvikvm is not associated with an android app, and is not running in a process that android is really even aware of, and generally can't use many of the android-specific apis.

Comment: So, is there a way to run Java in Termux in such a way that it CAN access the Android APIs?

Comment: You would have to use some form of IPC with an actual android app.